# Can I use the replaceFirst method to look for a string pattern and replace it?

Tags: java, str-replace

I have a question involving the Replace Method. I saw a question similar to this on here, but I tried to do the replaceFirst but it didn't work for me.  Is there, any way I can use the replace method to change a string that results in: Helle, Werld; to get it to result to BE "Hello, World" using the replace method. Is there a way using the replaceFirst method for me to search for the sequence of "le" and replace it with "lo" and also change "We" to "Wo"?. Please see my code below:

```
public class Printer
{

/**Description:  Replacement class
 * 
 * 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String test1Expected = "Hello, World!";


    String newString1;


    String test1 = "Holle, Werld!";

    newString1 = test1.replace('o', 'e');
            //Could I do:  newString1.replaceFirst("le","lo);


    System.out.println("newString1 = " + newString1);
    //Output comes out to "Helle, Werld!"



}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two regular expressions separatelt one after the other. Please try the following

```
newString1 = newString1.replaceAll("le", "lo").replaceAll("We", "Wo");
```

Comment: Thank you Amit, much appreciated!  I didn't know I could do that either using the newString1 variable I had assigned!

Comment: @Niklas Holle Werld is already converted to Helle Werld. Am just converting further. I will change the name of the variable though. Thanks!